# How to copy videojs from one div into another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I have a div with videojs in it

```
<div id="video">
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="200" height="200" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to copy this video into another div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var video = jQuery('#video').clone(true, true);
    jQuery('#block').append( video );
});
```

It copies that video player, but it doesn't work (can't play the video). What is the right way to copy videojs from one div into another div?

Comment: are you getting any JS errors in Console? What does the player return/display when you try to play the video after moving it over?

Comment: no errors, when clicking the play button nothing happens

Comment: I tested your code with Chrome and it works for me.

Comment: Just cloning the DOM isn't enough to create a working video.js player. What exactly are you trying to achieve that you'd need two copies of a player?

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain... I thought of a solution to re-create a new video based on the information available from the existing video, but still had issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Video JS installed but it seems like all you need to do is re-initialize the player itself.

Reference: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html

> If your web page or application loads the video tag dynamically (ajax, **appendChild**, etc.), so that it may not exist when the page loads, you'll want to manually set up the player instead of relying on the data-setup attribute. To do this, first remove the data-setup attribute from the tag so there's no confusion around when the player is initialized. Next, run the following javascript some time after the Video.js javascript library has loaded, and after the video tag has been loaded into the DOM.

```js
videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

> The first argument in the videojs function is the ID of your video tag. Replace it with your own.
>   The second argument is an options object. It allows you to set additional options like you can with the data-setup attribute.
>   The third argument is a 'ready' callback. Once Video.js has initialized it will call this function.
>   Instead of using an element ID, you can also pass a reference to the element itself.

```js
videojs(document.getElementById('example_video_1'), {}, function() {
  // This is functionally the same as the previous example.
});
```

```js
videojs(document.getElementsByClassName('awesome_video_class')[0], {}, function() {
  // You can grab an element by class if you'd like, just make sure
  // if it's an array that you pick one (here we chose the first).
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alvarez I updated my answer, may be that will help you.

Comment: @Alvarez what happens when you copy over the video and then trigger `videojs("element_id", {}, function() {});` ? Can you update your code where you actually do this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole HTML from id#video into id#block like this:

Example: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/T4qjlenn

```
 $( "#copy" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( "#video" ).html();
  $( "#block" ).html( htmlString );
});
```

Comment: It could work with regular video, but the problem is that it's video.js